# Exclude category from woocommerce query

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to list categories but i need to exclude couple. How can I add exclude category to the following?

```
        $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
        echo $product->get_categories('<p>' . _n( '', '', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>' );
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

the below example uses is_home. But you can also use the is_page() function to check for the page you are using and then apply the pre_get_posts.

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1,-1347' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```